# In A/B test, how to deal inconsistency between unit of experiment and unit of analysis in the experiment design?

Tags: experiment-design, ab-test

In the experiment, the metrics we care about is clicks per page (#clicks / #pages).

When performing the experiment, the unit of diversion we randomized on is "user" instead of "page".

I'm confused about what unit of analysis I should use in the analysis for significance.

If I use "page", I'm concerned that I would be violating one of the assumptions in hypothesis testing: the units should be independent. Since randomizing by "user" would mean some pages belong to the same user are correlated.

If I use "user", that means I'm calculating *clicks per page* for each user, then take the average *clicks per page* on users. This way, I'm concerned that the average will not be weighted, i.e., a user that had 1 pageview and clicked (click per page: 100%) will be weighted the same as a user that had 100 pageviews and clicked once (click per page: 1%). In this example, the clicks per page averaged on user would be (100% +1%)/2 ~= 50%, but the weighted average click per page is (1+1)/(1+100) ~= 2%.